# Finder search of string erroneously returns no results yet substring correctly returns results

Tags: finder, macos, spotlight, search, bug

Encountering a really bizarre error on a new iMac (5K, Late 2015) that is running Sierra.

There is a folder called "Job applications" in my Documents folder that shows up in a Finder search of This Mac with a search string of "Job".

A search string of "Job applications", however, returns no results at all.

Oddly, "Job ", "Job a", "Job ap", "Job app", etc. through "Job applicatio" returns results that include the folder.
[image: "Job applicatio" search]
But as soon as the string is "Job application" all search results disappear.
[image: "Job application" search]

Other folders have the same issue while others do not.  If I make a brand new folder called "Job applications", the problem persists.  My old iMac (27", Late 2009) running El Capitan (from which I transferred the files to my new iMac) has the same issue.  My Macbook Pro (Retina, 13", Early 2015) running Sierra does not have the problem.

I believe Finder uses the same index as Spotlight, which is confusing since Spotlight correctly returns the results.  I rebuilt the index for the Desktop folder, which contains some of the problematic folders, to no avail.  Any ideas?  I'll try rebuilding the entire index in the meantime.

Thank you